# Google Kick Start 2020 Round A Allocation Problem - WA error

Tags: algorithm

**Problem**

There are N houses for sale. The i-th house costs Ai dollars to buy. You have a budget of B dollars to spend.

What is the maximum number of houses you can buy?

**Input**

The first line of the input gives the number of test cases, T. T test cases follow. Each test case begins with a single line containing the two integers N and B. The second line contains N integers. The i-th integer is Ai, the cost of the i-th house.

**Output**

For each test case, output one line containing Case #x: y, where x is the test case number (starting from 1) and y is the maximum number of houses you can buy.

```
int main(){
    int tests, size, b;
    cin >> tests;
    for(size_t j = 0; j < tests; ++j){
        cin >> size >> b;
        int cur;
        vector<int> prices(size);
        for(size_t i = 0; i < prices.size(); ++i){
            cin >> cur;
            prices[i] = cur;
        }
        int cur_total = 0;
        int count = 0;
        sort(prices.begin(), prices.end());
        int i = 0;
        while(cur_total + prices[i] <= b){
            ++count;
            cur_total += prices[i];
            ++i;
        }
        cout << "Case #" << j+1 << ": " << count << endl;
    }

}
```

The above is my solution and when I run it locally with a test case, it is returning a correct output. Can anyone see a problem with my code??

Comment: Try using `long` instead of `int` for `cur_total` and `b` variables. Since, max no of elements are `10^5` & each element can  have max value `1000` max value of `cur_total` is `10^8` and can exceed range of `int`. These constraints should have been mentioned in the question.

Comment: @simran-ahuja I don't understand. Max int value is about 2 10^9

Comment: You must check that index `i` remains lower than the number of houses, to avoid an out-of-bound access. In other words, if you are rich enough, you can buy all the houses, but not more.

Comment: @Damien The number of bytes occupied by the int data type, and therefore the range of values it can represent, varies from one compiler implementation to another. Thus, I prefer to be careful and use `long int` in such scenarios. And, yes there is no check for `i <= size` in while loop. I missed that too, thanks.